# Lifetime of Object (Class and method)

Tags: c#

I just wanted to get advice the code below. Essentially, I want to know WHY I can instantiate an object and assign it to the variable newTask in the Class and then be able to do the same thing to the same variable name newTask in the method Button2Click?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    TaskTypes.Task newTask = new TaskTypes.Task();

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newTask.setName("Clean the toilet");
        textBox2.Text = newTask.getName();

    }

    void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newTask = new TaskTypes.Task("Why isnt this part failing?");
        textBox2.Text = newTask.getName();
    } ...
```

Comment: They are the same variable. Why would they not be? You've only declared a single variable (class member field)

Comment: Another thing to mention: if you made `newTask` `readonly`, you wouldn't be able to reassign it. Except, of course, for in the class's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two concepts here:

1. Scope of the variable
2. Memory reference

With scope, everything is clear - the variable declared in the class is a class member and accessible from anywhere in the class.

Now, when you assign a variable to new instance of an object, this variable is holding reference to it. You can assign new instances as many times as you wish. The old instance will lose reference, so, technically speaking, it is not going to be rooted anymore and it will be available for garbage collection. There are cases of read-only variables (class members) which can be assigned only once.

**Additional Answers:**

**I think I'm really confused between an instance and an object** - instance = object. In .net everything is a Type. All types derive from type "Object". Commonly, any heap-memory-stored objects called reference-types or "objects". Stack-stored primitives called value-types.

**1. The object is the TaskType** - yes. TextBox also object, namely - control

**2. I created an instance and passed the string "clean the toilet"** - yes. Instance- your code loaded into memory.

**3. The variable is newTask** - yes

**4. I then assigned a new instance to the variable newTask** - yes.

**5. The original instance "clean the toilet" was collected by the garbage collector?** - not immediately. When certain conditions are met for garbage collector to run.

Comment: So - Just to clarify (I think I'm really confused between an instance and an object). 1. The object is the TaskType 2. I created an instance and passed the string "clean the toilet" 3. The variable is newTask 4. I then assigned a new instance to the variable newTask 5. The original instance "clean the toilet" was collected by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 2):

This is called scope, it defines where a variable is visible.

You are using the same declared variable, but using the class instance in the first button click, then using a new instance in the second button click.

Comment: ah - understood, I'll go re-read on instances and objects. (Thank you)

Comment: Scope and eligible for garbage collection are not the same in C#. An object is eligible for collection as soon as it is no longer accessed. This might be very different from the scope of the reference.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Brian, I was typing too quickly and completely lost my train of thought. Updating answer.

Comment: What do you mean "same declared object"? The variable is the same, but the two objects are definitely different. And if `Button2Click` is called first, `Button1Click` will use the new instance.

Comment: @Gabe - I meant declared variable, updating answer. My apologies for the poor wording.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared in a class are available (have scope) to all members of that class.